# angularjs on url change trigger

Tags: javascript, angularjs

how to trigger window.scroll(); or window.resize(); angular when url state is changed ?

```
app.config(function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider){
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/home");
    $stateProvider 
        .state ('home', {
            url: '/home',
            templateUrl: 'views/home.html',
        })
        .state ('page', {
            url: '/page',
            templateUrl: 'views/page.html',
        })
});
```

Problem is for example "home.html" height is 300px, and "page.html" height is 1200px.
After URL changes and content, you cannot scroll down.

Comment: What's in the other parts of your html files?

Comment: well, post a bit more code, what about CSS or HTML ? Using jsbin would be helpful. It sounds like you're having some sort of Content limiting, e.g. somewhere a "height" of 300px or overflox:hidden sth?

Comment: @FerTo when i resize window, everything is ok. But when it loads first time without any triggering you cannot scroll

Comment: @gordon33 as I said, you're only posting a code snippet with that I don't know what is wrong. a) Post more code b) post a jsfiddle / jsbin

Comment: https://wrapbootstrap.com/theme/material-admin-responsive-angularjs-WB011H985 - i bought this template and edited some html only.